# How to set default mpicc

Tags: mpi

Recently, I have installed intel compiler, I loss the information for the set default mpicc, How can I set the following default in an easy way?

```
CC variable not set, 
CC  = /usr/bin/mpicc 
CXX variable not set,
CXX = /usr/bin/mpicxx 
FC variable not set, 
FC  = /usr/bin/mpif90 
FF variable not set, 
FF  = /usr/bin/mpif77
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try `export CC=/usr/bin/mpicc` and so on.

Comment: @N0rbert , i haved used this method, but It doesn't  solve this problem, namely which mpicc
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.7.259/linux/mpi/intel64/bin/mpicc